# Stop external library access to runnable Jar

Tags: java

So I have a Java application I will be releasing to one of my communities for a price. The app is just about complete and ready to be obfuscated but the problem is;

I found that when I add the Jar to another project in Eclipse you can instantiate classes externally and use my program as an external library to make scripts outside of my program. This is not what I'm wanting to achieve here... I'm self taught so I have grey areas of knowledge as I haven't learned formally, but I'm pretty experienced in Java still... I've tried googling it and nothings coming up, maybe I'm not phrasing it correctly. But if I could get some help it would be appreciated.

**Here is my structure of my packages:**

```
src.com
Contains main class
src.com.scripts
Contains Abstract Script class
src.com.scripts.impl
Contains the actual scripts that extend the abstract Script class
```

**What I've tried doing:**

I removed the public Identifier from the Abstract Script class but then it isn't visible to the main class to call it from as it is in the package before. So how can I go about this when my project is sorted in packages and they all need to access eachother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution.

If people want to reverse engineer your code, they will. There is nothing you can do to change that. `public`/`private` are essentially meaningless beyond helping you write good portable code.

That being said, Java is generally much easier to reverse engineer and make bindings to than other languages. Java doesn't inline functions and unless told otherwise, it will even leave all of your class and method names intact. If you had used a language like C, the optimized binary would be a bigger pain to work with, but the result would still be the same.

Just obfuscate the jar and call it a day. **Manually changing how you write your code is more harmful to you than it is to them.**

Comment: Hey, not sure if you got what I was getting at, but I'm not concerned about reverse engineering, its the fact you can add my jar to a program and access my methods inside. I've tried adding random runnable jars and some don't have any libraries that show. Even if I open the file with winrar it has plenty of class files in it. Isn't this to do with the class modifier?

Comment: Guess I can use protected class modifier right and change the structure of my packages?

Comment: @JoeTaylor You can just use reflection to make make any variable public, remove final modifiers, and much more at run time. Also yes, `.jar` files are glorified `.zip` files. However, there isn't really anything you can do to remove the `.class` files. `.class` files are just compiled `.java` files. Besides switching to a different programming language, there isn't a solution to your problem because that's not what Java is for. It sounds like you may be trying to use Java for something it isn't.

Comment: Well can't you prevent reflection with Java Security manager?

Comment: Sure, but if it is being used as a library, they can just provide a security manager before you have the chance to and override your changes. There is no way around it.

Comment: Yeah true, well that sucks. Still going to change my structure as I know it won't stop anyone who really wanted to get info from the program, but will at least deter the average person